# React js not rendering a object whose element is a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to render the P_words list element word with react using map:

```
const f_data = {
key: 2412,
reviewed: 100,
rating:4,
P_words: [{
    word: "Coolx",
    freq: 5
},
{
    word: "Dumbf",
    freq: 6
}
```

]

So this is the code inside my function to render this list:

```
          <ul>
        Cool
        {f_data.P_words.map((obj) => {
          <li key={obj.freq}>{obj.freq}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
```

I checked the DOM it shows cool but it shows a empty ul tag. Sorry if this is kind of vague.

Comment: Not related but suggest to use obj.word as your unique key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a `return` from `.map`, if you choose to use curly braces, you need to explicitly return something

```js
      <ul>
        Cool
        {f_data.P_words.map((obj) => {
          return <li key={obj.freq}>{obj.freq}</li>
        })}
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try directly using parethesis:

```
<ul>
        Cool
        {f_data.P_words.map((obj) => (
          <li key={obj.freq}>{obj.freq}</li>;
        ))}
      </ul>
```

Because it miss the return